# how to use maven resource plugin correcly

Tags: maven, build, pom.xml, maven-resources-plugin

There was a build failure when the project clean and install,

i think reason to build failure is maven resource plugin.

i have gotten the following error during the build the project

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@70dea4e]
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/sonatype/plexus/build/incremental/BuildContext;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0 (Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields (Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields (Class.java:1916)
at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints (InjectionPoint.java:675)
at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields (InjectionPoint.java:380)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:164)
at com.google.inject`enter code here`.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies (InjectorImpl.java:613)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup (InjectorImpl.java:569)
```

following errors were also shown when debugging

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.291 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-04T02:15:13+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) on project cas: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources: Lorg/sonatype/plexus/build/incremental/BuildContext;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7
```

following maven resource plugin was used in the pom

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>
```

please help me to solve this problem, i have tried many ways to resolve this , but still couldn't find a solution for this.

i am using the following maven version

```
buddika@buddika-pc:~$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T13:28:13+05:30)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.5.2
Java version: 1.8.0_73, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /home/buddika/installs/JDK8/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-98-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Thank You...

Comment: Please show the full pom file....cause that's looks strange.....

Comment: this was sorted out by using the maven 3.5.2, thnks for asking

Comment: I don't think so..please show the full pom file so it could be checked what the real problem is?...

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/sonatype/plexus/build/incremental/BuildContext.   Means there is no jar of sonatype..add that jar and try to build..
Remember NoClassDefFoundError means jar is not present in your local.. add it and try..

Comment: this was sorted out by using the maven 3.5.2